# How do I convert a string of words into multiple rows of a Table using MySql command Line

Tags: mysql

I have a string such as,

> "This is a sting and I dont know how long I am"

I want to turn every word in string into a row for my sql table so that I get:

> This
> Is
>  a
>  string 
> and 
> I 
> dont 
> know 
> etc...

I need to be able to do this with the MySql command line. (I also need an adjacent column to all be filled with ones on every row, incase that helps/changes your answer) I was thinking I could somehow use `INSERT String (Words, num) Values (@words, 1)` but I dont know how to get it to add every word. Is there any easy way to do this? If not, how would it be done?

Comment: Please respond and/or mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a function to split a delimited string. This problem is heavily discussed on [MySQL manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#comments) (search "split"), although there is no direct solution to handle variable number of elements.

Instead of that, I would help myself to generate such a query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ("', REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(string_column), '"', '\\"'), ' ', '", "'), '")') FROM t2_with_string
```